# Why does getchar() recognize EOF only in the beginning of a line?

Tags: c, eof

This example is from the K&R book

```
#include<stdio.h>


main()
{
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while(getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

[image]

Could you explain me why it works that way. Thanks.

^Z^Z doesn't work either (unless it's in the beginning of a line)

[image]

Comment: Can't see the example.. Can you post the code here?

Comment: That's a "feature" of the Windows shell. On Unix, you can type EOF at the end of a line by typing Ctrl+D twice; try typing Ctrl+Z twice. (Or redirect input from a file.)

Comment: typing Ctrl+Z twice or more doesn't work anyway

Comment: I know this is completely irrelevant and sorry for nitpicking, but it'd be good if one doesn't waste space with images, when plain text would perfectly suffice, and in this situtation, SO would nicely syntax highlight too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional UNIX interpretation of tty `EOF` character is to make blocking `read` return after reading whatever is buffered inside a cooked tty line buffer. In the start of a new line, it means `read` returning 0 (reading zero bytes), and incidentally, 0-sized `read` is how the end of file condition on ordinary files is detected.

That's why the *first* `EOF` in the middle of a line just forces the beginning of the line to be `read`, not making C runtime library detect an end of file. *Two* `EOF` characters in a row produce 0-sized read, because the second one forces an empty buffer to be `read` by an application.

```
$ cat
foo[press ^D]foo <=== after ^D, input printed back before EOL, despite cooked mode. No EOF detected
foo[press ^D]foo[press ^D] <=== after first ^D, input printed back, and on second ^D, cat detects EOF

$ cat
Some first line<CR> <=== input
Some first line <=== the line is read and printed
[press ^D] <=== at line start, ^D forces 0-sized read to happen, cat detects EOF
```

I assume that your C runtime library imitates the semantics described above (there is no special handling of `^Z` at the level of `kernel32` calls, let alone system calls, on Windows). That's why it would probably detect EOF after `^Z^Z` even in the middle of an input line.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. ^Z^Z or more doesn't work if there are another characters in this line before it.

Answer (score 0):

The program will read `EOF` only at the actual end of the input. If your terminal/OS/whatever only permit files to end at the start of a line then that's where you'll find them. I believe this is a throw-back to old-fashioned terminals where data was only transmitted a line at a time (for all I know it goes back to punched card readers).

Try reading your data from a file that you've preprepared with an EOF mid-line. You may even find that some editors make this difficult! Your program should work fine with that as input.

Answer (score 0):

[EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) indicates "end of file". A newline (which is what happens when you press enter) isn't the end of a file, it's the end of a line, so a newline doesn't terminate this loop.

Depending on the operating system, `EOF` character will only work if it's the first character on a line, i.e. the first character after an `Enter`.  Since console input is often line-oriented, the system may also not recognize the `EOF` character until after you've followed it up with an `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have the same question as you. When I want to end the function `getchar()`, I have to enter 2 `EOF` or enter a `<ENTER>` plus a `EOF`.

And here's an easier answer I searched about this question:

> If there is characters entering in the terminal, EOF will play the role as stopping this entering, which will arouse a new turn of entering; while, if there is no entering happening, or in another word, when the getchar() is waiting for a new enter(such as you've just finished entering  or a EOF), the EOF you are about to enter now equals "end of file", which will lead the program stop executing the function getchar().

PS: the question happens when you are using `getchar()`. I think this answer is easier to understand, but maybe not for you since it is translated from Chinese...