# Does ctrl+z count as a character in a program to count the number of characters

Tags: c, eof

The following is a program to count the number of characters:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while(getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

As we have seen here- [Why does getchar() recognize EOF only in the beginning of a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436596/why-does-getchar-recognize-eof-only-in-the-beginning-of-a-line) that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> is not considered as EOF when written within a line of characters and is considered as EOF only when written at the beginning of line.

So these are some of the following outputs of the program:

```
123
abs
^Z
8
```

Here the program returns 8 so it means it is counting the '\n' as well.

```
123^Z
abs^Z
^Z
8
```

It again returns 8 so what is the program doing here? Either it is ignoring ^Z as a character or it is not counting the '\n' after the ^Z.

```
abc^Zaa
^Z
4
```

Here the program is returning 4 so it means that it is not counting aa after <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. So I want to know whether it is not counting any characters after ^Z or it is also not counting ^Z but is counting the newline character at the end of each line. So can it be said that ^Z here is also acting as sort of end of line?

Comment: The question is more about the keyboard interface and driver than C:  What keys it counts as a _character_.  Keys Ctr Z becomes character `'\1A'` or signals an an "End-of-file" under different conditions.

Comment: Recommend printing the value returned by `getchar()` for greater insight.  `int c; while((c = getchar()) != EOF) printf("%d %d\n", ++nc, c);`

Comment: Also, year 1999 was 19 years ago - you should write standard C, not some prehistoric variant - `int main(void)`. And @chux perhaps, `printf("%d %hhu", ++nc, (unsigned char)c)`

Comment: @chux But here it is also apparently not counting any characters after ctrl+z and also this is not the case with other key combinations such as ctrl+s or ctrl+g as it easily takes them as characters and count them along but some key combinations e.g., ctrl+f rather than being written as ^F perform certain action and are not even taken as input.

Comment: Recall these are _control_ characters.  There are meant to act differential then other characters as they control input.  The precise functionality varies amongst computers.

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` is the end of file when it is read from the keyboard. When a real file is read from the disk, `'\1A'` (`Ctrl-Z`) is a character like any other. It doesn't signal anything. The file end is computed using the file length (the information is stored by the file system). `Ctrl-Z` is treated as the end of input because there is no way to know in advance the length of the input when it is read from the keyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does getchar() recognize EOF only in the beginning of a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436596/why-does-getchar-recognize-eof-only-in-the-beginning-of-a-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may depend on your OS, but in general at the beginning of the line it means *close the input stream* and in the middle of a line *flush input stream*. So in any case your control char is available on input (except if you modify the terminal behavior). Try this and you will see:

```
int c;
while((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
    ++nc;
    printf("read ascii code %d\n",c);
}
```

Comment: But what does it mean to flush input stream

Comment: That's another problem, but shortly input chars are not available at the time you input them, only when the terminal input buffer is flushed (when it is full, when you enter <enter> and when you enforce flush).